# How the second line of a file with javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to go through a text file and place data into a table each line in the file contains data for each column in the table.

First column of table = first line in text file

Second column of table = second line in file.

EDIT:
 ive been using the following but it returns only the first line and using it more than once in the same script over rides the previous line so i can only use it once,

```
 var XHR = new XMLHttpRequest();
     XHR.open("GET", "file.txt", true);
     XHR.send();
     XHR.onload = function (){
     var change = document.getElementById("tag").innerHTML = ( XHR.responseText.slice(0, XHR.responseText.indexOf("\n")) );
     };
```

the file looks like:

```
345343
345455
345345
353454
354354
```

Comment: please describe more about your question

Comment: is it a csv file?

Comment: @israel.zinc the file is a .txt file

Comment: Can you put one or two lines of your text file to help us understand your problem?

Comment: i have solution but fear to post because without checking out people are downvote my ans :(

Comment: I'm really writing this post one sec.

Comment: @israel.zinc is that better? Sorry i was in traffic on my phone so i was vague wont happen again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok dont know its works for you or not i just want to share.
i use this in my project and free to ask if you face problem :)

```
<div id="line2here"></div>
var client = new XMLHttpRequest();
client.open('GET', '/yourfile.txt');
var txt = client.responseText.split("\n");
document.getElementById("line2here").innerHTML = txt[1];
```

Comment: this works but it returns the first line. Question: doest the txt[1];    does that mean line one or reference one

Comment: yes try txt[0],txt[1], and so on you will  get your answer :)